# JSON [object Object] to string

Tags: javascript, json

I have and object I would to extract "error" form.

```
[{"name":"Whats up","error":"Your name required!"}]
```

The inspector renders object format

```
[Object]
     0: Object
          error: "Your name required!"
          name: "Whats up"
```

How do I extract the error only if I do not know object names. I tried Object.Object[0].error

Answer (score 1):

Your object is in a list - hence the square brackets. So, take the first element of the list, and then access its property:

```
var yourObject = [{"name":"Whats up","error":"Your name required!"}];

var firstElement = yourObject[0];  // firstElement is now = {"name":"Whats up","error":"Your name required!"}
console.log(firstElement.error);

// or immediately:
console.log(yourObject[0].error);
```

Example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsg7qe87/

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd access parts of a JSON object.

```
var obj = [{"name":"Whats up","error":"Your name required!"}];

console.log(obj[0]);
> {"name":"Whats up","error":"Your name required!"}

console.log(obj[0].name);
> "Whats up"
```

So you'd just use:

```
obj[0].error;
```